MySQL syntax error for doctrine blob field
I've created a Doctrine ORM entity with a property of type BLOB:
public const MAX_BLOB_SIZE = 2097152;
        
#[ORM\Column(name: 'blob', type: Types::BLOB, length: self::MAX_BLOB_SIZE, nullable: FALSE)]
private $_blob;

public function setBlobStream($blob) : void {

    if (!is_resource($blob)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Expected a resource, got ' . gettype($blob));
    }

    $this->_blob = $blob;

}

When setting this field and persisting this object using the entity manager i always get a syntax error:
$asset->setBlobStream($uploads['payload']->getStream()->detach());
$em->persist($asset);
$em->flush();

// An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'blob = '????\\0\u0010JFIF\\0\u0001\u0001\u0001\\0H\\0H\\0\\0??\\0C\...

One thing I did figure out is that the doctrine DBAL has a specific parameter type you should specify for storing large objects (\Doctrine\DBAL\ParameterType::LARGE_OBJECT), but I cant seem to figure out if I need and/or can specify this for the ORM aswel.
Got any suggestions?

Hi Ken, we currently use (lowercase) blob as column name, this works just fine for our current in-house developed ORM which uses MySQLi which we are deprecating.I do realize this is not the best name for a column and we will move away from it.

I finally found the issue myself.
It appears that (As a previous user commented and unforunately deleted) that the column name being blob was the issue. I think that doctrine does not escape the column name using backticks for the MySQL adapter.
